# Frequency of location updates decreases with background location tracking and FusedLocationApi

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, fusedlocationproviderapi

Google Play Services' Fused Location Provider Api lets you request location updates with location listeners or pending intents. I can successfully request location updates with the location listener but I have been struggling to replicate the same behaviour with pending intents. For the latter, I launch an intent service which handles the location data. What I have noticed during testing is that the location updates correspond with the interval I set in the location request. However, as time goes by the interval between updates increases tremendously even though the interval in the location request has remained constant. I have noticed this behaviour on several occasions with multiple devices. Does anyone have an idea what could be going on?

Foreground location tracking

```
protected void requestLocationUpdates()
{
    mIsTracking = true;
    LocationRequest locationRequest = mLocationRequests.get(mPreviousDetectedActivity.getType());
    if (locationRequest != null)
    {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "onLocationChanged");
    handleLocationChanged(location);
}
```

Background location tracking

```
protected void requestLocationUpdates()
{
    LocationRequest locationRequest = mLocationRequests.get(mPreviousDetectedActivity.getType());
    if (locationRequest != null)
    {
        mResultCallabackMessage = "Request location updates ";
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = getLocationPendingIntent();
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                locationRequest, pendingIntent).setResultCallback(this);
    }
}

protected PendingIntent getLocationPendingIntent()
{
    if (mLocationPendingIntent != null) return mLocationPendingIntent;

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationUpdatesIntentService.class);
    mLocationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    return mLocationPendingIntent;
}

public class LocationUpdatesIntentService extends IntentService
{

    public LocationUpdatesIntentService()
    {
        // Use the TAG to name the worker thread.
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        Location location = (Location)   bundle.get(FusedLocationProviderApi.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);

        handleLocationUpdates(location);
    } 
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: your problem is that location request increases or decreases ?  In title you write decreases in text increases..

Answer (score 0):

It could be because some other application in the device must have requested for more frequent updates. Please refer this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest#setInterval(long)) for more details

> This interval is inexact. You may not receive updates at all (if no
>   location sources are available), or you may receive them slower than
>   requested. You may also receive them faster than requested (if other
>   applications are requesting location at a faster interval). The
>   fastest rate that that you will receive updates can be controlled with
>   setFastestInterval(long)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem too, but as **@Shiv** said you should be testing different parameters:

```
 mClient.requestLocationUpdates(LocationRequest.create(), mLocationIntent)
```

try this:

```
 mClient.requestLocationUpdates(createLocationRequest(), mLocationIntent)

private LocationRequest createLocationRequest() {
    LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setMaxWaitTime(MAX_WAIT_TIME);
    return locationRequest;
}
```